# Is a SAS function need to translate into hive query?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

The below mentioned SAS script needs to be translated into hive, can anyone suggest how I can do this in SQL?

```
ARRAY variable {1:5} column1-column5;
DO k = 1 TO 5;
         IF DATEPART(variable{k}) <= DATEPART(date_column) THEN variable{k}=DATEPART(variable{k});
         ELSE variable{k} = .;
         END;
```

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Hi Gordon,They are defining array of  variable that is 1 to 5 and in the next step The first time the loop processes, the value of count is 1 then if its is less than equal to date_column then it should be variable 1 or else variable = .           This logic need to convert into hive..I dont have sample data